# Batch script to test if a folder exists fails when checking a UNC path

Tags: scripting, batch

I've written a small batch file to help us with a server migration to remap user directories using GPO.

However in the batch file I'm having a syntax problem that appears right but it's still failing. Here is what I have so far below.

```
If exist "\\server\UserData\%username%"     
GOTO :UNMAP    
ELSE    
NET USE H: \\newserver\UserData\%USERNAME%    
:UNMAP    
NET USE H: /DELETE /Y    
NET USE H: \\newserver\UserData\%USERNAME%
```

Now when I run it I get the following:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
C:\>if exist "\\server\UserData\userfolder"
```

Any idea how to resolve this or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

`goto :unmap` should be on the same line as the `if`

even better, simplify the whole thing like this:

```
If exist "\\server\UserData\%username%\." NET USE H: /DELETE /Y
NET USE H: "\\newserver\UserData\%USERNAME%"
```

Comment: Awesome that fixed that line.  Now it's barking at my else command.  So I tried moving the lower line up below the else as well thinking that would be the same thing but that didn't work.

Comment: Get rid of ELSE altogether.  Instead, put in a GOTO after your first NET USE line that skips the :UNMAP section.

Comment: you don't need the goto line at all. Longneck's script by itself should do what you want it to do. It removes the drive mapping if it's there and then maps the drive you want to the new server.

Comment: frankly, you don't even need the if. just blindly delete the h: drive. you're going to remap it on the next line, so who cares if it returns an error?